# ldapmodify failing implementing TLS certs

Tags: linux, centos, ldap, openldap, slapd

I'm probably overlooking a typo, but i cant find it.

```
~$ /usr/bin/ldapmodify -H ldapi:// -Y EXTERNAL -f /tmp/certs.ldif
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: 
gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
modifying entry "cn=config"
ldap_modify: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
```

---

```
~$ cat /tmp/certs.ldif
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcTLSCertificateFile
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/openldap/certs/ldap.crt
```

---

```
grep -R olcTLS /etc/openldap/slapd.d
/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config.ldif:olcTLSCACertificatePa th: /etc/openldap/certs
/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config.ldif:olcTLSCertificateFile: "OpenLDAP Server"
/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config.ldif:olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/openldap/certs/password
```

---

```
ls -la /etc/openldap/certs/ldap.crt
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2282 Aug 20 17:42 /etc/openldap/certs/ldap.crt
```

Answer (score 0):

After changing folder ownership, ldapmodify was able to succeed.  Not quite sure why as I made sure **other** was able to read and execute the folders and the certificates and key were readable by **other** as well.

```
~$ sudo chown ldap:ldap ./certs/ ./private/ ./cacerts/

~$ sudo chown -R ldap:ldap ./private/ ./cacerts/

~$ ls -la
total 24
drwxr-xr-x.  7 root root  122 Aug 20 17:42 .
drwxr-xr-x. 78 root root 8192 Aug 20 18:07 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  2 ldap ldap   20 Aug 20 17:42 cacerts
drwxr-xr-x.  2 ldap ldap  106 Aug 20 17:42 certs
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  121 Jan 29  2019 check_password.conf
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  363 Jan 29  2019 ldap.conf
drwxr-xr-x.  2 ldap ldap   22 Aug 20 17:42 private
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root 4096 Aug 20 17:42 schema
drwxr-x---.  3 ldap ldap   45 Aug 20 17:42 slapd.d

~$ /usr/bin/ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:// -f /tmp/certs.ldif
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
modifying entry "cn=config"

~$ grep -R olcTLS /etc/openldap/slapd.d
/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config.ldif:olcTLSCACertificatePath: /etc/openldap/certs
/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config.ldif:olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/openldap/private/ldap.key
/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config.ldif:olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/openldap/certs/ldap.crt
/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config.ldif:olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/openldap/cacerts/ca.crt
```